# Click Once Deploy/Setup Project

Tags: deployment, localization, installation, culture

im getting the following errors when i set ProjectProperties->Publish->Options->Publish Language to German:

Warning 1   Could not match culture 'de-DE' for item 'Windows Installer 3.1'. Using culture 'en' instead.   ******
Warning 2   Could not match culture 'de-DE' for item '.NET Framework 3.5'. Using culture 'en' instead.  *****

Im using German Vista, VS however is english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't have the german versions of these two packages. They come along with Visual Studio, which in your case is English.

Look at the **The ClickOnce User Interface** section of this [site](http://sumithtv.tripod.com/) . It gives you the details of what you can do to workaround this problem.